# Creating a table that can drag and drop both columns and rows on React

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop

I want to create a table that can drag and drop both columns and rows on React. I've look at other solutions like [react-beautiful-dnd](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd), [table-dragger](https://github.com/sindu12jun/table-dragger), etc. The best one I've found so far is [ag Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php) but that would require me to get the license. I have been looking for other solutions out there and even trying to build this functionality myself in React. Does anyone have an insight on how to implement this functionality or even recommend other solutions that could help achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 5):

There are different packages that you can use for this purpose that are open-source. No need to implement it yourself. Some examples that are worth looking into:

1. [react-table-hoc-draggable-columns](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table-hoc-draggable-columns)
2. [react-sortable-hoc](http://clauderic.github.io/react-sortable-hoc/#/basic-configuration/basic-usage?_k=5cgrgl)
3. [material-table](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table)

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a deeper look at all these options. However, just taking a glance at these options, they don't seem to support drag and drop on **both** rows and columns at the same time. (sorry about not being clear about that) Any insight on how to maybe use any of these libraries to achieve that functionality?

Comment: The `Grid` option in `react-sortable-hoc` appears to allow you to drag and drop both rows and columns.

Answer (score 2):

[dnd-kit](https://github.com/clauderic/dnd-kit) helped me achieve column and row dragging. The trick was enabling column **OR** row dragging only when each is needed. It seems unlikely a UI would need a column and a row to drag simultaneously. So in my case if I hover on a column header dnd-kit uses horizontal dragging settings but if I hover on a row "header" then dnd-kit uses vertical dragging settings. That makes it appear like they can both happen when really it's one at a time.

Here are some relevant lines of example code to get started.

```
const [columnHover,setColumnHover] = React.useState(false);
<DndContext
    modifiers={[columnHover ? restrictToHorizontalAxis : restrictToVerticalAxis]}
>
    <SortableContext
        items={columnHover ? columnIDs : rowIDs}
        strategy={columnHover ? horizontalListSortingStrategy : verticalListSortingStrategy}
    >
        ...
    </SortableContext>
</DndContext>
```

[image: Table with row and column drag]

Comment: Do you have a code sandbox you can share?

Comment: I don't, sorry. It would be unreasonable to try to separate those bits from the rest of the product.

Comment: Could you let us know how you got the borders of the rows / columns to move along? When i tried to make the rows move the borders of the td elements stayed in place for some reason...

Comment: @TheTruth I don't use HTML Tables in my product since I find them to have too many old quirks. I use DIVs with [CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) applied. I ended up using [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) for the border lines.

Comment: @TheTruth I used some pseudo elements to solve the problem you mentioned. I gathered "isDragging" property from `useSortable` to determine which  column or row was being dragged. Then I used that to apply a CSS class like ".dragging" to that column/row. Finally I use something like this:
`.dragging:before {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        pointer-events: none;
        background-color: light-grey;
        box-shadow: 0 0 1px grey);
        z-index: 2;
}`