# Creating a table that can drag and drop both columns , rows and cell on React

Tags: reactjs, datatable, drag-and-drop, antd

I want to create a table that have these feature in React JS :

1- can drag and drop both columns and rows.

2- can drag and drop both cell.

Comment: Similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59135980/creating-a-table-that-can-drag-and-drop-both-columns-and-rows-on-react

Comment: Yes, but I want to create a table that can drag and drop both columns , rows and cell, the problem is in the cell